# When one of these two equations has integral sol, why p=3 (mod 4)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let p is not 7 and p be an odd prime.
AND ***one*** of two equations

$x^2+7y^2=p, x^2-7y^2=p$

has integral sol (x,y). then show that $p \equiv3 \pmod4$

what i have done is this, in $\pmod7$, two equations are $x^2 \equiv p \pmod7$

and $p$ can be only $1$ or $2$ or $4$ by testing from $1$ to $7$

Comment: Let $x=1,y=2$. Then $p=29$ from the first equation and $29 = 1 \pmod 4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x^2+7y^2=p$. Applying modulo 4:
$$x^2+3y^2=p \pmod 4 \tag1$$ then $$x^2-y^2=p \pmod 4 \tag2$$ Because $p,4$ are coprime from (2) we get $x \ne y \pmod 4$.

Because $a^2 \in \{0, 1\} \pmod 4 \ \forall a$, we have $x^2=0,y^2=1$ or $x^2=1,y^2=0$.

From the first case we get $p = 3 \pmod 4$ and from the second case $p=1 \pmod 4$.

Both cases are possible:

1) $x=2, y=1$ then $p=11$ and $11 = 3 \pmod 4$

2) $x=1,y=2$ then $p=29$ and $29 = 1 \pmod 4$

Therefore your claim $p \equiv3 \pmod4$ is false.